# where should I store connection strings when running azure function locally

Tags: python, azure-functions

I'm working on a http-triggered azure function and testing locally.  My azure function connects to sql database. I want to store connection strings somewhere (environment variables?) so that they do not show up in the code. And azure function can still access the connection strings like below:

```
server = os.getenv('SERVERNAME') 
database = os.getenv('DBNAME') 
username = os.getenv('DBUSER') 
password = os.getenv('PWD')
```

I created user environment variables (SERVERNAME, DBNAME, etc) on my local computer, but the azure function doesn't not seem to be able to access those.

Does anyone know how to set those environment variables so that my azure function can access the variables using `os.getenv()`?  I'm on windows.  Thanks.

Comment: you want to create an ARM template, and part of that deployment, you'd be fetching your secrets from key vault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#environment-variables).

[image]

If you develop azure function on the azure portal, you can store `Environment variables` in `application settings`.

If you develop azure function locally, you can store it in `local.settings.json` file.

**Example**

local.settings.json

[image]

I did a test, and found no problem.

[image]